# Determining planarity??

Tags: graph-theory

[image]
Sorry i couldnt think of any way to ask this so i took a picture of it and pasted it below.
I'll start with what little i do know, firstly this graph is not homemorphic to  $K_5$ simply because that would require 5 vertices of degree 4 which we clearly don't have ( only 3) i also can't seem to figure out hot make it homemorphic to $k,3,3$ though i think i could label it as a bipartite graph in some was where everything was degree 3 i cant find a way to do that with only 6 vertices.

Lastly i don't think its planar why? if you cut out b1b4, b2b5 and a6b3 it becomes obvious by looking at it that you can't untwist it in two dimensions.

Please help thx.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph

Comment: @RahulNarain, this is not the Petersen graph.

Comment: @Easy True, but it contains the Petersen graph as a subgraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being non-planar doesn't mean being homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.  Rather, a graph is non-planar if and only if it contains either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.  Here, a graph $H$ is a *minor* of a graph $G$ if $H$ can be obtained from $G$ by deleting vertices, deleting edges, and/or contracting edges.  (I.e., $G$ has a *subgraph* homeomorphic to $H$.)

Here's a hint for this problem: show that your graph contains $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.